# How to have different size of generic for each class

Tags: java

first of all a big thank to community for answering lately some of my question and improve my knowledge.

So first of all i have a map where i store class and the object of that class:

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends AbstractSkillPoint<?>>, AbstractSkillPoint<?>> POINT = new HashMap<>();
```

Then i have the method where i retrieve the `AbstractSkillPoint`:

```
    public <T, E> T getValue(final Class<? extends AbstractSkillPoint<?>> clazz, final Player activeChar, final T defaultVal, final Object... parameters)
    {
        final AbstractSkillPoint<T> point = (AbstractSkillPoint<T>) POINT.get(clazz);

        if (Objects.nonNull(point))
        {
            return point.getValue(player, defaultVal, parameters);
        }

        return defaultVal;
    }
```

Here's my `AbstractSkillPoint`:

```
public abstract class AbstractSkillPoint<T>
{
   public abstract T getValue(final Player activeChar, final T defaultVal, final Object... parameters);
}
```

And an example of a new class which extends `AbstractSkillPoint`:

```
public class SkillPointExampleLv1 extends AbstractSkillPoint<Long>
{
     @Override
     public Long getValue(final Player activeChar, final Long defaultVal, final Object... parameters)
     {
         // Some custom code here
         return defaultVal;
     }
}
```

My question is the following:

How do i call properly from `getValue` method each give all the different parameters on that method and then inside each class instead of have varargs:

```
public Long getValue(final Player activeChar, final Long defaultVal, final Object... parameters)
```

to have the objects as the class have them example:

```
public Long getValue(final Player activeChar, final Long defaultVal, final Player otherPlayer, final double discount)
```

Now varargs do the work and fetching the data is no big deal but i want to learn different approach.

Answer (score 2):

The point of using an interface/an abstract class is to have always the same contract, independently on how such contract is implemented behind the scenes.

If your abstract class declares the method:

```
public abstract T getValue(final Player activeChar, final T defaultVal, final Object... parameters);
```

... then it means that you guarantee to the caller that, no matter what the implementation is, they will always be able to call your `AbstractSkillPoint` by passing a `Player`, a `T` and a varargs `Object...` for the parameters.

If you were declaring the signature of `SkillPointExampleLv1` differently than this (as you suggest), then it would simply mean that `SkillPointExampleLv1` wouldn't really be an `AbstractSkillPoint`.

But if you wonder about it, maybe this is not what you really want to do... And if that was the case, then maybe you should share some more details about what these objects are to see if another design pattern is applicable.